# OpenMP scalability with large file I/O

Tags: c++, performance, openmp

I have a C++ code shown below with OpenMP.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
const int rowSize = 10000;
const int N = 200;
const int nrow = 100; // variable

int main() {
    // initialise the results vector and a shared vector
    vector<int> results((long)nrow*rowSize);
    vector<int> sharedArr(rowSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < rowSize; ++i) sharedArr[i] = (rowSize-1-i);

    ifstream f("some_40GB_file", ios::binary);
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < nrow; ++i) {

        // load a row from the file
        long filerow[rowSize];
        #pragma omp critical
        {
            f.seekg((long)i*rowSize*sizeof(long));
            f.read((char*)filerow, rowSize*sizeof(long));
        }

        // do some computations and store it to the results vector
        for (int j = 0; j < rowSize; ++j) {
            long res = filerow[sharedArr[j]];
            for (int k = 0; k < N; ++k) res += (j+k) * k*k;
            results[(long)i*rowSize+j] = res;
        }
    }
    f.close();
}
```

It seems that the code does not scale well with the number of `nrow`, especially when it's `nrow = 100000` or higher. Here is some timing test results:

```
serial:
nrow:   100,    300,    1000,   3000,   10000,  30000,  100000, 200000, 300000
time:   0.196,  0.601,  1.872,  5.611,  19.796, 57.474, 192.787,392.584,580.323

parallel (8 cores):
nrow:   100,    300,    1000,   3000,   10000,  30000,  100000, 200000, 300000 
time:   0.047,  0.134,  0.396,  1.164,  3.875,  11.574, 55.219, 108.113,224.322

speed up:
nrow:   100,    300,    1000,   3000,   10000,  30000,  100000, 200000, 300000
result: 4.17    4.48    4.73    4.82    5.11    4.97    3.49,   3.63    2.59
```

The runtime scales well for the serial program. However, the parallel program does not scalle well above `100000`.

Why is this happening? I suspect there is something to do with I/O access when the index is more than integer limit (i.e. `2^31`), but I am not sure.

It also seems that the maximum achieved speed up is 5.11 while there are 8 cores available. Is there any way to make the parallel code more efficient?

Comment: The #prama omp critical might be killing performance, because it forces serialisation. Can you try to read serial from the file and process it parallel after with the #pragma openmp parallel?

Comment: What kind of system is this? Processor, OS, Memory, Storage/filesystem where the file resides? How did you measure the time? In what order did you run them? Any I/O measurements with less transfer than available memory are vulnerable to variances due to transparent caching/prefetching by the OS or I/O library.

Comment: @Zulan I am using Amazon AWS EC2 c3.2xlarge (8 vCPU, 15 GiB memory, 160 GB storage) with Ubuntu 16.04. The file resides on the same directory with the program. It was timed using built-in `time` command from Linux. Compiled with `g++ -O2 parallel.cc -o parallel.out -fopenmp`

Comment: Not only is the critical section forcing serialisation it's also forcing the i/o system to hop about all over the file.  First thread `0` seeks position `0`, then thread `1` seeks position `0+chunk_size`, then thread `2` seeks position `0+2*chunk_size`, then thread `0` seeks position `1`, ...  (Other sequences of reads are possible.) I pity the read head.  Do as @OutOfBound suggests and (re-)serialise the file read operations.

Comment: Don't use `seekg()` - as others have posted, that causes all kinds of performance issues.  You'd be better off using an OMP-shared variable called something like `rowToRead`, starting it off at zero, and in the critical section reading rows serially, using a private such as `myRow` to save `rowToRead`, and incrementing `rowToRead` so the next read (presumably by another thread entering the critical section) gets the next row.  Then use `myRow` instead of `i` to determine where in the `result` vector your result gets placed.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark It's probably even a bit worse than that - the call to `seekg()` likely invalidates whatever data might be buffered by the `ifstream`, causing more data to be read from disk than necessary.

Comment: Since you have lots of RAM, you could possibly use memory mapped files.